# How do I listen to tap gestures on different controls in the same view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two copies of a control (its called a `RatingControl`). How do I write handlers that can be invoked on the correct object when somebody double taps on them?

I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl2: RatingControl!
```

inside a `TableViewController` and then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: ratingControl, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:)))
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)

    let tapGR2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: ratingControl2, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:)))
    tapGR2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR2)

}
```

`RatingControl.doubleTap(_)` is an innocuous event handler.

When there is a double tap on the second rating control, the `doubleTap` method is called but is dispatched on the first rating control object!

I have tried setting two targets on a single `UITapGestureRecognizer` but it runs into the same problem.

Thanks much!

Comment: How about:
   `let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:)))
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    ratingControl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)

    let tapGR2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:)))
    tapGR2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    ratingControl2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR2)`

Comment: Sigh. Thanks much. That worked like a charm.

Comment: @nynohu Instead of posting a bunch of unreadable code in a comment, why not post an answer?

Comment: @rmaddy ok i got it, posted as answer.

Comment: If we've answered your question you should accept one of the answers. Pick the one that you think answers best, or the FIRST one to answer your question in the case of a tie for answer quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the gesture recognizers to the two rating controls instead of to `self.view`.

Try this:

```
let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:)))
tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
ratingControl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR) // ratingControl, not self.view
let tapGR2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RatingControl.doubleTap(_:))) 
tapGR2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
ratingControl2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR2) // ratingControl2, not self.view
```

Comment: Yeah, I said that. I think it's better to explain what to change, and why, than to simply provide drop-in code changes with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to hooking up a gesture recognizer: the target, which determines which object gets notified when the recognizer is triggered, and the view it's attached to, which determines from which view the recognizer recognizes the gesture.

You've got 2 gesture recognizes configured the same way, both attached to `self.view`. They are therefore going to respond to taps on self.view (which I assume is the view controller's content view.) I don't think it's clear which gesture recognizer is going to be triggered when you tap in that case.

You should have 2 different views and attach a different gesture recognizer to each one. If `ratingControl1` and `ratingControl2` are view objects, perhaps you meant to attach the gesture recognizers directly to them, rather than to `self.view`?

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Really appreciate it. The documentation is confusing about the role of target and attachment. Your reply clarifies.

Comment: If we've solved your problem then you should accept the answer that you feel best addresses your question.